# RESt api: identification of resource and content varying based on authentication

Tags: api, http, rest, hateoas

I'm designing an API following the HATEOAS / RESt principles.
Yet I'm not sure about this basic point: **identification of resource.**

Suppose this url: **/images**
which exposes all the images uploaded by an user (to this user).

Suppose I use an oauth access token for the authentication purpose, the content of /images will vary based on the Authorization header.

Does this break the identification of resource concept ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  A resource does not have to be static to be restful.  Imagine a webservice that provides time-of-day:

```
 Http://www.myservice.com/current-time/
```

Nothing in the rest playbook would demand that this not work as expected. 
 The case with the photos is that your service is returning a resource represented based on info set in the request--filtering out all non-user owned photos by auth header. Your still returning the same general thing, a collection of photos.

Not much different than saying with the response type header you want a json representatio vs an xml representation returned.

Things get fishy when you switch results completely, like one person gets a collection of images while another is provided last weeks transcript of Glee at the same resource location.

Comment: I was wondering if this url will be better: __/users/{identifier}/images.__ But, your first sentence "A resource does not have to be static" is pretty clear. Thanks.

Comment: @ludofleury i actually prefer your second resource url format you have in your comment. It adds clarity--you'd expect only the user's images based on the url alone.  Still, nothings technically wrong with the original.

Comment: Yeah, my main problem is: users aren't suppose to know the url /user. That's why I'm based on access token. They don't have to fetch their own id. Thanks again