# Are resources state aware or static under hateoas/restful api

Tags: api, rest, http, oauth, hateoas

My question is about if resources should be aware of the state or statically defined. For example, I have an API that returns account information where the resource uri would be `/api/accounts/2`.

If I'm authenticated as user `henk willemsa` the resource would look like this:

```
{
   "id": 2,
   "firstname": "henk",
   "lastname": "willemsa",
   "birthday": "12-31-1980",
   "email": "firstname.lastname@email.com",
   "other": "other useless info",
   "super-secret-info": "some super secret info"
}
```

Is it good practice to return the resource with stripped out data if you would be authenticated as another user? For instance, making a request to the same endpoint `/api/accounts/2`, but for a different user, `jan smit`, the returned response would be:

```
{
   "id": 2,
   "firstname": "henk",
   "lastname": "willemsa"
   "other": "other useless info"
}
```

The idea is that user `jan smit` is only allowed to see the public data, where `henk willemsma` sees the secret as well.

Would it be better for something like this be solved with 2 endpoints, where `/api/accounts/2` would return a 403 for user `jan smit` and 200 for `henk willemsa` and another api endpoint `/api/public-account/2` would return 200 for the both users? The later could give a response like:

```
{
   "id": 2,
   "firstname": "henk",
   "lastname": "willemsa"
   "other": "other useless info"
}
```

Having one endpoint and stripping out data would in my eyes be inconsistent, because the structure of the data-type/resource would change depending on who requests it and not because extra explicit data is sent, which changes the data-type/resource (like filter options).

But I can also see that splitting this out over multiple endpoints could cause for having lots and lots of different endpoints which basically do the same returning account information.

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718772/rest-api-identification-of-resource-and-content-varying-based-on-authentication), which somewhat describes what I'm looking for but is about collection calls. In my opinion, these are allowed to return different unique resource, but the data-types should always be the same. In my example, `/api/accounts/` would always return a list of accounts, but depending on which user makes the request to the endpoint, while the size of the list could be different, it would always be a list of accounts.

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

The "best" approach can probably not be objectively defined. However, creating multiple resources for the same "thing" is probably not a good idea. Things should be identifiable by URI, so accounts should have a stable URI.

I would probably just omit the fields that the user can not see, if that is possible according to the data definitions/structure. If not, you could serve multiple 'representations', i.e. media-types, and let [content-negotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) handle the exchange. That means you create 2 media-types, one with the full data and one for the restricted view of the account, and serve both for the same resource URI. The server then can decide which representation you get based on your credentials. The client would also be able to easily see which representation it got, and inform the user if necessary that it has a restricted view of the account.

The client would have to ask with an 'Accept' header similar to this:

```
Accept: application/vnd.company.account-full; q=1.0, application/vnd.company.account-restricted; q=0.9,
```